Confused about AUTOSAR AP accessing to method result
AUTOSAR AP defines Request&Response approachs for users, its format just like this
ara::core::Future<Output> user_defined_method(Input in)

As you see, AUTOSAR AP uses Future to wrap output and standars describes two concepts to access output: Event-driven and polling
Event-driven
Usage like
...
auto fut = obj.user_defined_method(input data);
auto output_value = fut.get(); // or fut.GetResult(), both will block current thread until fut' state changs to ready
...

AUTOSAR calls this way Event-driven !!!???, confuse me very much.
polling
Usage like this
auto fut = obj.user_defined_method(input data);
while (!fut.is_ready()) {
    sleep(xxx);
}

// Being here means that fut state is ready

auto output_val = fut.get(); // or fut.GetResult(), both will return immediately.

AUTOSAR calls this as no-blocking !!!??? confuse me very much again
Beside above, there is another interface:
template <typename F>
auto Future::then(F && func) -> see autosar definition {}

can somebody help me to understand where to use this approach, thank you:)
